# Reading same file from multiple processes using python

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

I have a template file used to make a lot of new files based on a parameter list. Since I am going to make 4000 files I tried us the multiprocessing module module. 
The code is about like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def make_file(x):
    Read textfile
    Use x to change it
    Save it with a new name    

if __name__ == '__main__':
        paramters = about 4000 parameters
        p = Pool(5)
        p.map(make_file,parameters)
```

But when I tried it, it hang after about 2000 files was made. Is it stupid to read from the same file with multiple processes?

Comment: You should acquire a lock for a file before trying to edit it. Otherwise race condition will occur and in result file may get corrupted.

Comment: the exact number it stops creating the files is actually important as you may be hitting a technical limit in your filesystem. Please provide more info on paths and files

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could post the code related to opening the template file and creation of the new file. You could have something like hash collisions in the file name creation.